# Gson malformed json

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I use `Gson` to transform my response to its model. When I copy the content of the json and paste it into a `String` manually, then it works perfect.

Like

```
String result = "...";
```

When I pass the response directly to `Gson`, then I get a following exception:

> Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 501 path $.contact.picture.links[0].href

This is my json:
[json requested file](https://api.betterplace.org/de/api_v4/fundraising_events/22798.json)

json:

> {   "id": 22798,   "created_at": "2015-05-19T19:31:56+02:00",
>   "updated_at": "2015-05-21T00:03:15+02:00",   "title": "Title
>   Charity",   "description": "",   "tax_deductible": true,
>   "donations_prohibited": false,   "closed_at": null,   "donor_count":
>   0,   "donated_amount_in_cents": 0,   "requested_amount_in_cents":
>   50000,   "progress_percentage": null,   "contact": {
>       "name": "R. Kocyigit",
>       "picture": {
>         "links": [
>           {
>             "rel": "fill_100x100",
>             "href": "https://asset1.betterplace.org/uploads/user/profile_picture/000/448/689/fill_100x100_xing-profile-photo.jpg"
>           },
>           {
>             "rel": "original",
>             "href": "https://asset1.betterplace.org/uploads/user/profile_picture/000/448/689/crop_original_xing-profile-photo.jpg"
>           }
>         ]
>       },

My code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Model model = gson.fromJson(response, Model.class);
```

Comment: Does that file contain the exact string you're feeding into Gson? (Have you printed it out to check?)

Comment: No, but if there are special characters, what can I do ? I cant edit the json in the server.

Comment: Please give us a complete, minimal, and reproducible example. Something short.

Comment: @Luser_k Is that a "No, the file doesn't contain the exact string I'm feeding into Gson" or a "No, I don't know"?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was during transforming the stream by network into the String.

When I use a BufferedReader to transform into a String, then Gson works well.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int read;
    char[] chars = new char[1024];
    while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
        buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

    return buffer.toString();
} finally {
    if (reader != null)
        reader.close();
}
```

Comment: What were you doing before?